# TypeError: (0 , apollo_server_core_1.ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground) is not a function

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I upgraded Nestjs server package and tried to start my server. This time I got the following error:

```
`TypeError: (0 , apollo_server_core_1.ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground) is not a function`
```

I puzzled...

Answer (score 6):

After a search I found that `ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground` depends on `apollo-server-core` package. I installed this package and the error disappeared:

```
yarn add apollo-server-core
```

or

```
npm install apollo-server-core
```

Comment: I unexpectedly encounter this error as well, and upon installing `apollo-server-core` did fix the error above.